# Support Sign in with Apple or nah?

Tags: mobile, apple, native-app

With the announcement of this...

> Sign In with Apple will be available for beta testing this summer. It will be required as an option for users in apps that support third-party sign-in when it is commercially available later this year.

Will you be supporting this in your mobile applications or dropping support for third-party logins?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the details of the service, but I suppose it would come down to security, privacy, implementation and user demographics concerns.

But given that similar services with Google, Facebook and Twitter has reduced friction in the login experience, I would place Apple's on the same boat. One more choice for the user to quickly login or register to the product.